# Can't use proxies with python

Tags: python, python-requests, http-proxy

So I'm simply writing a script to test out the proxies in python, but I can't get it to work. I always get a `Proxy Error`

The very simple code:

```
import requests

def normal():
    response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/',
                       proxies={
                           'http': 'http://myUserNameUrlEncoded:myPasswordEncoded@uk2049.nordvpn.com',
                           'https': 'http://myUserNameUrlEncoded:myPasswordEnco@uk2049.nordvpn.com',
                       }
                       )
    print(response)
```

The error I get is the following:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6d123be640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')))
```

First thing I notice... why is the host being taken as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)?
This seems to be random when it does this, and when the host is successfully set to `uk2049.nordvpn.com` it still times out. (I've already tried increasing the timeout).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT*
I figured out the problemm is only with https proxies. For some reason, python is taking the host to be the url I'm sending.

Comment: Your `https` proxy URL starts with `http://`, is that correct? It's not supposed to be `https://`?

Comment: The docs have it as `http://` I've tried both though
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: Is the proxy working otherwise?

Comment: Outside of python? Yeah :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long overdue answer, turns out the requests module doesn't handle https proxies. To take advantage of this, use pycurl ‍♂️